# Is it possible to use anonymous records

Tags: f#

I have a function which log exception and any record, which was the reason of  exception:

```
let logExceptionWithObject(exn: exn) (obj: Object) =
    try
        delimiter()

        FSharpType.GetRecordFields (obj.GetType())
        |> Array.iter (fun f -> 
                        logger.Error(f.Name + " " + f.GetValue(obj).ToString())
                      )  

        logger.Error(exn.Message)
        logger.Verbose("{@Exn}", exn)
    with
        | exn -> Console.WriteLine(exn.Message)
```

I can call this function with any record which I have created  type for. But sometimes I need to call this function with record I have no type declaration for:

```
logExceptionWithObject exn { A = 10; B = 20; C = "some" }
```

I don't want to declare type for each of such records, but the compiler  gev me error:

```
The record label 'A' is not defined.
```

Is it  possible to use anonymous records ?

Comment: Sorry, no, F# doesn't have anonymous records. But why do you need them anyway, if you're just going to use them as a dictionary? Just use a real dictionary!

Comment: I am just trying to use "native" F# types when it is possible.  Thanks for hint, I will use Dictionary.

Comment: F# has [`Map`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/collections.map-module-%5Bfsharp%5D) - that's native.

Comment: FSharp now supports anonymous records: https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/master/FSharp-4.6/FS-1030-anonymous-records.md

Answer (score 8, accepted):

F# does not have anonymous records. But in your example, you don't need them anyway, because you're only using them as dictionaries, so why not use real dictionaries?

But wait, you don't even need a dictionary - all you need is just a list of key/value pairs, that's it.

```
let logExceptionWithObject(exn: exn) map =
    try
        delimiter()
        map |> Seq.iter ( fun (k, v) -> sprintf "%s %s" k v |> logger.Error )
        logger.Error(exn.Message)
        logger.Verbose("{@Exn}", exn)
    with
        | exn -> Console.WriteLine(exn.Message)
```

Usage:

```
logExceptionWithObject exn [ "A","10" ; "B","20" ; "C","some" ]
```

Comment: Note that in a list of tuples like Fyodor's usage example there, you don't actually need the parentheses around the tuples. If it helps you to see them better, you can write `[ ("A","10") ; ("B","20") ; ("C","some") ]`, but it's not actually necessary to write the parentheses, as Fyodor demonstrated.